# Count the number of expired & unexpired rows for each unique id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
| id      | certificate|expires   |
|       1 |        123 |12-DEC-15 | 
|       1 |        123 |12-DEC-09 |
|       1 |        123 |13-DEC-09 |
|       2 |        456 |14-DEC-16 |
|       2 |        456 |14-DEC-09 |
|       2 |        789 |14-DEC-09 |
|       2 |        789 |14-DEC-09 |
```

I'm trying to sum the number of certificates for each user which are expired and have not expired like this:

```
 |id | expired | unexpired |
 |1  |2        |1          |
 |2  |3        |1          |
```

I've managed to count all the certificates that have expired but it only puts out the number of rows that are not expired. How do I get the number of expired certificates?

```
   SELECT 
      id, 
      COUNT(certificate) as numcerts, 
      expires
   FROM 
     certificates
   WHERE 
     expires > current_date()
  GROUP BY id
  having numcerts > 0
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: You explicitly filtered them out by `expires > current_date()`

Comment: use STR_TO_DATE to make that text into a proper date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the dates are stored in `date` datatype then the below query will give you the result

```
select 
id, 
sum( case when expires < curdate() then 1 else 0 end ) as expires,
sum( case when expires > curdate() then 1 else 0 end ) as unsepired 
from certificates group by id
```

If the dates are stored as varchar the way you have in the given example then you need to use `str_to_date` function

```
select 
id, 
sum( case when str_to_date(expire,'%d-%b-%y') < curdate() then 1 else 0 end ) as expires,
sum( case when str_to_date(expire,'%d-%b-%y') > curdate() then 1 else 0 end ) as unsepired 
from certificates group by id
```